# Enable redux-form and set focus to field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I've got disabled form field by default and when user clicks on button `Edit`, it will enable the field. I also want to set focus on the field, but I don't know how. I've created `ref` to the field and tried some `focus()` function on it, but it hasn't worked. You can try it here on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mq7wwj3w7y).

Comment: Two reasons **1)** you're using a custom `TextField` stateless component: `component={TextField}`. You cannot assign a ref to a stateless component. Convert `TextField` to a class component. **2)** You need to add the [`withRef`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1933) prop to your reduxForm `Field` component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You must assign the ref to the input element instead of the Field component
2. Add an callback to set in your parent component the reference of subcomponent input
3. Use the reference to focus the input when pressing the edit button:

https://codesandbox.io/s/rlx390xn6m

Answer (score 1):

just HTML's `autofocus` is much better:
https://davidwalsh.name/autofocus

- in react use with camelcase: `autoFocus`