# Focus redux-form element onClick of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using below code to generate input field using redux-form

```
    import { Field } from 'redux-form';
    focusForm(){
    }

    <Field
        onClick={() => this.showMessage()}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholderText}
        ref="qaQuery"
        className="form-control"
        type="text"
        component="input"
        name={"inputField"}
        id={this.props.name}
    />
    <Button onClick={() => focusForm()}
```

I want to focus the field onClick of button.
how we can achieve this.
I tried with below options:

```
this.refs['qaQuery'].focus() //Not working - return Field and not actual input filed
document.querySelector("input[name='inputFileName']").focus(); //bad method
```

Please help me to achieve this, thanks

Comment: `this.refs[qaQuery].focus()` is wrong. Try -> `this.refs["qaQuery"].focus()`

Comment: Yeah tried same but not working coz qaQuery is ref for redux form

Comment: Adding to @AnandUndavia comments, you should use [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) instead of string refs

Comment: Problem is with redux form element, with normal input file we can use ref and its working

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51267666/3719788) might be helpful.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42459190/2405689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my answer:

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
    focusForm(){
        this.refs['qaQuery'].getRenderedComponent().focus();
    }

    <Field
        onClick={() => this.showMessage()}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholderText}
        ref="qaQuery"
        className="form-control"
        type="text"
        component="input"
        name={"inputField"}
        id={this.props.name}
    />
    <Button onClick={() => focusForm()}
```